# Showing $ \left\lVert P_C(x) - x \right\rVert_2^2 \le \left\lVert x - c \right\rVert_2^2 - \left\lVert P_C(x) - c \right\rVert_2^2 $

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, projection

$C$ is a convex set and $ x \in R^d. P_c(x) $  is the orthogonal project of $x$ onto $C$ and $c \in C$. I want to show that

$ \left\lVert P_C(x) - x \right\rVert_2^2 \le \left\lVert x - c \right\rVert_2^2 - \left\lVert P_C(x) - c \right\rVert_2^2  $

My approach is using triangular inequality for $ \left\lVert P_C(x) - x \right\rVert_2^2$

$ \left\lVert P_C(x) - x \right\rVert_2^2 \ge \left\lVert P_C(x) \right\rVert_2^2 - \left\lVert x \right\rVert_2^2$.

We can multiply this by minus as all terms are $ \ge0 $. So

$ \left\lVert P_C(x) - x \right\rVert_2^2 \le \left\lVert x \right\rVert_2^2- \left\lVert P_C(x) \right\rVert_2^2$.

Adding $\left\lVert c \right\rVert_2^2$ and substracting it.

$ \left\lVert P_C(x) - x \right\rVert_2^2 \le \left\lVert x \right\rVert_2^2- \left\lVert c \right\rVert_2^2 - ( \left\lVert P_C(x) \right\rVert_2^2  - \left\lVert c \right\rVert_2^2)$.

But I am cannot progress after this step.

Is there any other way to show this inequality using properties of the orthogonal projection on to convex sets.

Comment: I understand that $C$ is the convex. What is $c$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net It was my mistake. $c \in C$. I updated the question

Comment: You are using the triangular inequality wrong, because you added squares to the norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use

$$
\|x-c\|_2^2 = \|P_C(x)-c\|_2^2+ \|P_C(x)-x\|_2^2 -2(P_C(x)-x,P_C(x)-c).
$$